# Why there are two "that" in one clause?

Tags: clauses

> "And he is able to get experience some things that because I work and because my husband works, that we're not able to give it at home..."
>
> "This was a goal, that once we reached retirement that we would find this farm."

The sentences above are from [Young Students Plant, Harvest, Learn about Farm Life](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/american-youngsters-plant-harvest-learn-about-farm-life/4140567.html)

Why there are two "that" in one clause? Or it's just because they're oral English?

Comment: It does sound like uncorrected transcription.  There should have been some indication of pauses as the speakers recomposed their utterances.

Comment: There are two *that* because the classes are badly written or badly translated. Either way they're bad English, and need to be corrected before anything about them is discussed.
The problem is made worse by the title *Young Students Plant, Harvest, Learn about Farm Life* which does seem fairly clear, but simply isn’t correct.
*Young Students Plant, Harvest* and *Learn about Farm Life* would be the most simple correction.
Even before that, the capitalisation is questionable. So what? So I'd rather not have anything questionable in any title of mine… What does it say about the contents?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Headlines are often ungrammatical because terseness is a priority.

Comment: Barmar thanks, and could you make that relevant, please?

Of course headlines are often ungrammatical - although almost never *because 'terseness' is a priority* - but what suggestion of anything like or to do with a headline do you see here?